# FileSavePicker for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, filepicker

Is there any way to create file in documents library of windows phone from the app. I did the same thing in windows 8 but for phone there is no FileSavePicker class. Only FileOpenPicker is present.

Answer (score 0):

I am no Windows Phone specialist, but I believe you can do something like that :

```
  Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker fop = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            var fileTOOpen = await fop.PickSingleFileAsync();

            var fo = await fileTOOpen.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            fo.WriteAsync(...
```